# Spring security authorization without authentication using role only

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to implement the authorization element of spring security into our application. We have an external authentication process, and just want to use spring security to stop people without certain roles from accessing certain URLs. We wish to pass the users role as a header in the http request, and determine whether the user can view the url without knowing anything about their name or password.

Having looked at a lot of documentation, I am yet to see an example of somebody doing this, but I believe that the way to go with it would be to extend the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and get the role out of the request like so:

```
public class RequestHeaderPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilterImpl extends
    AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

   private final String PRINCIPAL_REQUEST_HEADER = "user-role";

   private final boolean EXCEPTION_IF_HEADER_MISSING = true;

   @Override
   protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
       String principal = request.getHeader(PRINCIPAL_REQUEST_HEADER);
       if (principal == null && EXCEPTION_IF_HEADER_MISSING) {
           throw new PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException(PRINCIPAL_REQUEST_HEADER
                + " header not found in request.");
       }
       return principal;

   }

   @Override
   protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
       return "N/A";
   }

}
```

My questions are:
1) Is this the correct way to go about solving the problem?
2) What would be the right thing to return as the principal? Would it be the role, or a UserDetails object containing information about a dummy user?
3) Will I be able to plug this into predefined Spring objects, or will I have to create concrete implementations for the Authentication Manager, provider etc?

Comment: How will you protect against someone just adding the role header themselves?

Comment: @LukeTaylor Currently the request is being sent from another server after the authentication has taken place. We are leaving it to the client for now to authenticate the user and add the right role. Although, i understand what you are saying and we are aware that we will have to refactor this at some point

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem was by creating implementations of the AuthenticationProvider and the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter. This allowed me to get the relevant header from the request, set the principal as the list of roles, and authenticate it myself.

My implementation of AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter:

```
public class RequestHeaderPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilterImpl extends
    AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

private final String PRINCIPAL_REQUEST_HEADER = "user-role";

private boolean exceptionIfHeaderMissing = true;

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String principal = request.getHeader(PRINCIPAL_REQUEST_HEADER);
        if (principal == null && exceptionIfHeaderMissing) {
            throw new PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException(PRINCIPAL_REQUEST_HEADER
                + " header not found in request.");
        }
        GrantedAuthority[] grantedAuthority = new GrantedAuthority[1];
        grantedAuthority[0] = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(principal);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(grantedAuthority[0]);
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
         return "N/A";
    }

    public void setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(boolean exceptionIfHeaderMissing) {
        this.exceptionIfHeaderMissing = exceptionIfHeaderMissing;
    }

}
```

My implementation of AuthenticationProvider:

```
public class AuthenticationProviderImpl implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException
    {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
            (Collection<GrantedAuthority>)authentication.getPrincipal();
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken auth =
            new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(null, null, authorities);
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

My Java application config:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-security.xml")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter roleFilter() {
        RequestHeaderPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilterImpl filter =
            new RequestHeaderPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilterImpl();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(true);
        filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        return new AuthenticationProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        List<AuthenticationProvider> authProviderList = new     ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
        authProviderList.add(authenticationProvider());
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new ProviderManager(authProviderList);
        return authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

My spring-security.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="roleFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN)"/>
    </http>

</beans:beans>
```

This seems really hacky, so I am more than willing to have a look at other suggestions. For that reason, I will leave this question as open and not accept this answer.