# configuring spring security only for authorisation?

Tags: spring-security, authorization

My application uses angularjs as front end and spring-security, spring mvc and hibernate on backend. Authentication process is through Facebook or twitter. (social authentication only). Now, my requirement is to handle only authorisation through spring security as authentication is done using Facebook. My only query is that how can I configure Spring- security to be used for authorization only and not for authentication. How can I achieve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using an implementation of AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.

Similar POSt [Spring security authorization without authentication using role only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326208/spring-security-authorization-without-authentication-using-role-only)

[Spring security authorization without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993491/spring-security-authorization-without-authentication)

Hope this helps.

THanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You should use OAuth 2.0

[http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html](http://syntx.io/integrating-your-java-spring-mvc-webapp-with-facebook-doing-the-oauth-dance/)

Here is Facebook tutorial: http://syntx.io/integrating-your-java-spring-mvc-webapp-with-facebook-doing-the-oauth-dance/